# Sort List and apply limit in Java 8

Tags: java, sorting

I'm using `List` in `java8`.

I have a list with custom class object. I need to fill this list with object in sorted form according to object property and after sorting I need to apply limit in list.

**For example**

```
  public class TempClass {
       String name; int count;
       //... Getter, setter and constructor
  }

  // Suppose I have a list with TempClass
  List<TempClass> tempList = new ArrayList<>();

  // There are five obj Of TempClass
  TempClass obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5;

  // I need to insert these object according to "count" property
  // Suppose obj1.getCount = 10, obj2 = 7, obj3 = 11, obj4 = 8, obj5=12
  /* I need to add element in order
      0 - obj5
      1 - obj1
      2 - obj3
      3 - obj4
      4 - obj2
  */
```

Second thing I need to apply limit in `List` after sorting. I need only 3 elements from Top in this case only `obj5, obj1, obj3`

Can you please let me know how can I do that ? I'm using java8 with Google cloud
endpoints

Comment: What have you tried to achieve it?

Comment: I'm not sure what I need to try

Comment: @AzeemHaider what ??? you know what to do right ??

Comment: Have you done any research before raising the question here? For example, search for "java list sort" and then "java list limit results" (hint: sublist), read about these and code something. If you're struggling with that code or you have issues with it, then you post a question here.

Comment: Thanks for `sublist` but what about sorting I'm using loop but it's not working fine. I'm new in java may be there is good way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PriorityQueue<TempClass> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingInt(TempClass::getCount));
for (TempClass temp : tempList) {
    queue.offer(temp);
    if (queue.size() > 3) {
        queue.poll();
    }
}

LinkedList<TempClass> result = new LinkedList<>();
while (queue.size() > 0) {
    result.push(queue.poll()); //obj5, obj1, obj3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found answer.

For `List` sort use lambda expression or Comparable.

Like this.

```
tempList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(t -> t.getCount()));
```

And for limit.

```
tempList= tempList.stream().limit(3).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It's an unnecessary sort for all number except top N.

Comment: @neuo how do you know which ones are at the top unless you sort them first?

Comment: @eis，use `Maximum heap` . Only keep `n` elements in container, and participation in comparison like my answer.

Comment: @neuo you're still sorting all the elements, you're just removing extra elements after each sort. It doesn't change the fact that you're still doing the sort for each element.

Comment: @eis, every loop, only compare with current 3 largest numbers. Time complexity is O(N * Log(K)), and your algorithm is O(N * logN). If N >> K, the difference can be great.

Comment: @neuo I was just commenting, so I don't see how there is such thing as "my algorithm". Also, I think we just disagree on the terminology here - even when you just compare current 3 largest numbers, you will anyway have to go through sorting for every item. Sorting is needed for all numbers in both your and Azeems answer, your answer just optimizes it to an extent.

Comment: @eis, sorry for the mistake. Every number except top K only be compared once, not sorted. Finally result don't know where other numbers should be order. Maybe we just have different definitions of `order`.

Comment: @neuo it's seems eis answer is good than me, isn't it. Is there any drawback in eis answer ?

Comment: @AzeemHaider I didn't provide an answer :) but I'd say your answer is just fine assuming tempList contains, say, <50 items, as it is very clear and easy to understand. If you want to prepare for bigger lists, then answer provided by neuo is good optimization.

Comment: @eis Oh.. Sorry, I interchange the names :P